# Is this inverse really unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am trying to show that for the operator $T:L^2(-1,3)\rightarrow L^2(-1,3),\ Tx(t):=tx(t)$ the inverse of $T-\lambda I$ is unbounded for $\lambda\in [-1,3[$. Part of the assignment focuses on the function

$$f(t)=\begin{cases}1,\ t\in [\lambda,\lambda+\epsilon],\\ 0,\ t\not\in [\lambda,\lambda+\epsilon].\end{cases}$$

Here $\epsilon >0$ is chosen such that $\lambda+\epsilon<3$. I have already proven that $||f||=\sqrt{\epsilon}$ and that $||(T-\lambda I)f||=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\epsilon^{3/2}$. I have been given a hint to use these results combined with the fact that I can write $f=(T-\lambda I)^{-1}(T-\lambda I)f$ (this is true since I have shown that $T-\lambda I$ is injective, i.e., a left inverse exists.

I asked about this earlier and some commented and said that the inverse was bounded. I've asked my professor about this problem and it should be the case that the inverse is unbounded but now I'm just confused about this. I've tried basically everything to try and show it is unbounded by using  the hint that is given but with no result. Every time I always end up achieving some bound for the inverse operator but on the assumption that it is bounded so that does not work.

Can someone give me any hints as to how to do this or if this inverse truly is unbounded (for $\lambda\in [-1,3[$)?

Comment: If $\|(T-\lambda I)x\|\leq C\|x\|$, then for $x=(T-\lambda)f$ you have that $\sqrt{\epsilon}\leq C\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{3/2}$ for all $\epsilon >0$. This implies that $1\leq C\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{1/2}$ for all $\epsilon>0$, which implies $1=0$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're saying. What is it that you have shown?. Did you mean that if $||(T-\lambda I)^{-1}x||\leq C ||x||$?

Comment: I think that is what you meant. Couldn't you also say from $1\leq C\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\epsilon$ then you would have $\sqrt{3}\epsilon^{-1}\leq C$. Then the constant can be as large as we want it to be since you can pick $\lambda$ closer and closer to 3 hence $\epsilon$ will be smaller and smaller thus $\epsilon^{-1}$ becomes larger and larger.

Comment: Yes, I missed writing th the exponent $-1$.

Comment: So does my argument hold? Cause it shows that I can make $C$ arbitrarily large. Is that enough to show that $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ cannot be bounded and hence it must be unbounded?

 And in your argument are you sure you can say for all $\epsilon >0$? Because $\epsilon$ is chosen such that $\lambda+\epsilon <3$ where $\lambda\in [-1,3[$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is a bounded operator $S$ such that $S(T-\lambda I)=(T-\lambda I)S=I$. Then $\|x\| =\|S(T-\lambda I)(x)\|\leq \|S\| \|(T-\lambda I)(x)\|$. This means $\int_{-1}^{3} |x(t)|^{2} \leq \|S\|^{2} \int_{-1}^{3} |t-\lambda |^{2}|x(t)|^{2}$ for all $x$. Take $x(t)=1$ for  $|t-\lambda | <\epsilon$ and $0$ elsewhere. Then you get $2\epsilon \leq 2\epsilon^{3}\|S\|^{2}$ which is contradiction if $0 <\epsilon <\frac  1 {||S||}$.